# Summarize Authorize Attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I have an ASP.net MVC website providing various admin functions.  It's internal and uses Windows authentication to manage different roles access to various controllers and actions.

In order to achieve this I have decorated the various objects with [Authorize(Roles="")]

This project is now quite mature, and a search reveals I have used the attribute nearly 60 times - I'm now at the point where this is starting to feel insecure, and I need a way to affectingly manage who has access to what.

So what I really want to build is a site map type page that lists all views on the site with a list of roles that can access each view listed alongside.

I have searched but can't seem to find how to start - any pointer would be greatly received - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're feeling insecure about not having all controllers/controller actions managed something you could look at is [Fluent Security](http://www.fluentsecurity.net/).

It allows security to be specified in a centralized space and in a way that is readable.

There's a good tutorial on it [here](http://www.mariusschulz.com/blog/securing-an-aspnet-mvc-application-using-fluentsecurity).

It won't give you your site map type page, but may give you some peace of mind.

Comment: Looks as good as anything I could have hoped for - the WhatDoIHave feature looks like the site map idea might also be possible!  Thanks

Comment: You should have a look at FluentSecurity + MvcSiteMapProvider. It might be what you are looking for: http://www.revium.com.au/articles/sandbox/fluentsecurity-mvcsitemapprovider-better-net-security-management/